# jQuery if statement doesnt seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an if statement and for some reason I cant seem to get it to work, Can anybody see why?

http://jsfiddle.net/7YKgS/1/

I have a span tag that contains a string and im trying ot say if this string == X then do this, if not do something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ($('span.errorp:contains("323ou")').length > 0) {
    //found at least one that contains the text
    alert('hi');
} else {
    alert('working');
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/7YKgS/4/

Answer (score 4):

you should do it like this

```
if(!!$('span.errorp:contains("323ou")').length ){
    alert('hi');
} else {
    alert('working');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `$` function of jQuery will always return a true value. Test its length to see how many matches it found (0 is a false value).

Answer (score 2):

To check whether a selector selects anything, use `.length`**: http://jsfiddle.net/7YKgS/5/**

The `length` property returns the number of matched elements. If there's no match, `.length` equals zero, and `$("..").length` evaluates to `false`. If there's any element, the expression `$("..").length` evaluates to `true`.

```
if($('span.errorp:contains("323ou")').length ){ //.length
   alert('hi');
} else {
    alert('working');
}
```

Comment: ehhhh it evaluates to `0` or a number greater than `0`... **not** `true` or `false`

Comment: @Neal Anything within the parentheses of an `if(...)` is parsed as a logical expression: (sub)expressions, separated by logical `&&` or `||` are interpreted as boolean values. So, if the expression is a non-boolean value, it's converted to `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("span.errorp").text().match("323ou")){
                       alert('hi');
                    } else {
                        alert('working');
                    }
```